# Do we need the [colon-equals] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Seeing a user is now in the progress of adding this tag to a bunch of questions I thought to deal with it now.

I personally see no value in the [colon-equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colon-equals) tag, but please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

The tag excerpt is:

> For questions regarding the `:=` operator available in several languages

Comment: Not being able to tag operators is a big honking problem.  I never, never, never want to see a ++ question again :)  But do notify the editor, mass tag edits need to be vetted by meta first.  A comment on one of his posts directing him to this meta question ought to do.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I didn't know about this rule about mass edits, I'll be sure to be more careful next time.

Answer (score -1):

<strike>Yea that should be merged into [assignment-operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assignment-operator).</strike> It should go. The language (which should be tagged) should be clear enough to know that it's `:=` in the code. Given the criteria for tags to be clear in most context and given Erik's comment below, it shows that there's cases that even I didn't know. I don't think anyone can be an expert with this operator.

Comment: The `:=` is an operator specifying which parameter you're passing to be able to pass parameters out of order in many languages, and it certainly shouldn't be merged with the assignment operator since that's a very different thing.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth fair enough.

Comment: I agree that no one can be an expert in this tag cross langages, but that's the case of many very useful tags like `out-of-memory` and hundreds of others

Comment: @Moody maybe (I kinda disagree though, you can get to be an expert in memory management, regardless of language) But 'these *other* tags are also bad' isn't a reason to create a new one. It's a reason to clean out the old ones, if anything.

Comment: so `parallel-processing` should be replaced by `r-parallel-processing`, `c-parallel-processing` .... declined in 1000 tags ? how are "secondary" tags not fine ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper i'm not saying that.

Comment: @moody again... You can become an expert in parallel processing  (understanding mutexes and semaphores,  how to apply them and the pitfalls of them). I don't see it being the same for an operator

Comment: and those are big general concepts that apply to most languages/frameworks, not a general language operator.

Comment: I get your point, thanks for developing, for me the bottom line is that it is useful and practical, and I solved for the community something that took me too much time to search for today, I'm worried that you don't see the usefulness because you didn't have to search for the kind of info contained into these posts, so I encourage you to do so before taking action, tell me what is the `:=` operator for in R without using my tag and see if I took away value by my action.

Comment: That's mildly upsetting but I understand you're doing what you do for the best of the community so thanks for what you're doing and take whatever decision you think best.

Comment: @Moody I just typed in := operator in R. On Google, not even need to make it a stack sitesearch. It got me pretty good stuff, including some of the very questions you tagged. No doubts the questions are useful. I don't see the tag making the difference here though (also my argument is about expertise, not searchability)

Comment: For most users, tags are not about expertise, but a way of searching for questions. And symbols are pretty hard to search for. I think it's a good idea to have tags for certain type of operator.

Answer (score -4):

Thanks for pinging me, I'm mainly a `R` user, and info regarding this operator was really hard to find, in fact I had to use google with a search like `site:stackoverflow.com ":="` to find anything. The google search itself is not obvious.

The name of the operator is not obvious either, and many questions regarding this operator are more or less duplicates of each other, now by seeing one question on the topic, related searches are made really easy. Now users will find it easily, it contains equal so even without encountering another similar question, users are likely to find it when exploring tags.

The tag would certainly have benefited much as I spent quite some time today trying to find info on this operator in the R language (try to do it without the new tag to see my point).

I don't know much about other programming languages but if you look at the tagged questions, a lot of users are confused about this operator, this will help clear the confusion.

Comment: if you were concerned about R, why did you tag Go and other languages? Could `r-colon-equals` be better?

Comment: I'm concerned about R but I'm thinking of other users too, now I can search `[r] [colon-equals]`, and `go` user can look for `[go][colon-equals]`, there was also a few cross language questions, it's much cleaner imo to have a general tag, like so many other tags are.

Comment: I hope the downvotes will be explained, and please provide a good alternative to find easily all the posts now tagged `[r][colon-equals]` next time I'm looking for them. If this tag isn't useful then half of the present ones aren't either.

Comment: How to find questions with symbols? Use a search engine that can deal with them. http://symbolhound.com/?q=r+:=

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I might need it at some point, but it's not common knowledge, and not practical at all, and I'd be happier if I search for SO posts using SO's search engine, that's a bit weird to rely on external search engines for issues that can be solved here.

Comment: @braiam Unfortunately I couldn't get any interesting link regarding `:=` through symbolhound.com

Comment: Well, search engine is hard. Google hasn't figured it out yet and that's their main business.

Comment: Indeed, tags work well on the other hand (not inferring your opinion on the current issue, but hammering the nail for other readers).